# Speed up archiving process, several apps

Tags: xcode, scripting, compilation

I have an iOS project configured with several targets. There is the main app and some other targets that just provide a different content, but with the same app structure. This translates in several apps (20+). The process to archive every single target is very time consuming, and I was wondering if there is a way of implementing an script for doing this.

**UPDATED**

I found in this link exactly what I was looking for

http://blog.octo.com/en/automating-over-the-air-deployment-for-iphone/

Comment: You don't need a script, just edit your main scheme to build the others as Dependancies.

Comment: But I need to create a .ipa file for every single target. Is what you propose valid for that?

Comment: Yes, they're called aggregate targets.  It's a pain to set up, but they work fairly well.

Comment: I got the thing of the aggregate target, I already put it and it is generating the .app files for every dependent target. I've been researching into it and seems like I'll need some custom build code to generate the IPA builts, right?

And what about once having these IPA, is there a way to automate the publishing process to the AppStore?

Comment: I sure hope there isn't (that would get really spam-bot-y really quickly)